# Can I open a new window(web page) who not default tab selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

For example, assuming that the same tab as the above image exists, the 'Active' tab is specified as default.

However, my client wishes to keep this default option and open a new window that different tab will selected.(second 'Link' tab or something.)

Is this possible? If it can, how to do this?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. but I could not even catch the feeling that it was possible..I need a hint to get started.

Comment: Such questions are too broad and not allowed on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you are using Bootstrap, you can remove all the attributes related to tab behavior from the `a.nav-link` and instead use `target:"_blank"`. Here in bellow example I have made added the `New Page` tab, there I have removed all the extra attributes and added `target` attribute.

*This example may not work within this snippet since it is within the nested frame, and opening the `_blank` tab from nested tab would be messy, but it works on web page I have tested it.*

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="https://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">New Page</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Home Page</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Profile Page</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Contact Page</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have `div` contains tab contents.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="link1" data-toggle="tab" href="?section=tab1">Tab 1</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="link2" data-toggle="tab" href="?section=tab2">Tab 2</a>
</li></ul>
```

Pass your `div` id as parameter `section` as href of `li`.

```
<div id="tab1">
</div>
<div id="tab2">
</div>
```

Then get the parameter, and scroll manually to the `div`.

```
<script>
    const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const section = params.get('section');

    if(section!=''){
        $('#' + section).addClass('active');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#' + section).offset().top
        }, 2000);
    }else{
        //Default tab here
        $('#tab1').addClass('active');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#tab1').offset().top
        }, 2000);
    }
</script>
```

Hope this would help.